# Get started with Selenium what am I missing for entering text into a textbox

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to get started with Selenium. Here is my simple code. Open StackOverflow and enter sdf in the search box. IE comes up and navigates to the correct page. Then things go south. Take a look at the output. This is in a console app.

UPDATE: I looked at the HTML in the driver... it's looking at the Selenium start page.

CODE:

```
IWebDriver _driver;
_driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
Console.WriteLine(_driver.PageSource);
_driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Clear();
_driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("sdf");
```

Output:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.28.0.0
Listening on port 60181
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>WebDriver</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<P id=main>This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.</P></BODY></HTML>
Unable to find element with name == q
DONE
```

Comment: May be the page is not getting loaded fully. Try using the below Wait before FindElement.                                           driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Answer (score 0):

Try with some other locator

```
By.cssSelector()

By.id()

By.xpath()
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should work.

form#search div input

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath of `//input[@name='q' and @placeholder='search']`